# Apply a radom pacing in Jmeter without using Timers

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I wanted to apply Pacing in jmeter for 120- 180 Seconds for all my samplers , I know i can do it with Through put Timers is there anyother way to apply pacing , i think we can use Beanshell Scripting but not sure of how to implement that .

This is the sample Beanshell that i reffered from internet a i tried , i used the random function to get a random pacing beetween 120 to 180 seconds and subracting it with Previous sample time . I think this implementation is wrong . could some of you suggest on this please . Thankyou .

Long pacing =${__Random(120000,180000)} - prev.getTime();

if (pacing > 0) {
Integer iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null;
log.info(String.valueOf(iPacing));
vars.put("mydelay", String.valueOf(iPacing));
return iPacing;
} else {
vars.put("mydelay", "0");
return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. You won't be able to implement pacing without Timers because you need to add a delay and [the relevant test element for introducing a delay is a timer.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)
2. If you want to introduce pacing using scripting be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so the obvious choice would be [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer)

Example code:

```
//Sets the pacing to be between 120 and 180 seconds
Long Pacing = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(120000, 180000)

//If the response time is less than the pacing ms, set the delay value to myDelay
if ( pacing > 0 )
{
    //iPacing is equal to the int value of pacing if pacing is not equal to null, otherwise iPacing is null
    Integer iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null;
    log.info(String.valueOf(iPacing));
    vars.put("myDelay", String.valueOf(iPacing));
    return iPacing;
}
//The response time is greater than or equal to 4500 ms, set myDelay to 0
else
{
    vars.put("myDelay", "0");
    return 0;
}
```